# What is the role of axis parameter in np.argmax()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Wee know, in [axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) parameter 0,1 means column and row wise maximum element index but
for 2,3 & so on what it indicates? An example code is given here. What is the output significance in this code?
[image: An example code]

Comment: Look at `np.array(a).shape`.  I expect (1,3,3). So axis parameter may be 0,1 or 2, but not 3.

Comment: With 3d arrays (and higher) interpreting the `argmax` result is a bit tricky.  In one sense the results are perfectly logical, but using them in any meaningful way is hard.  `np.take_along_axis` was added to make this a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an array of higher dimensions you will also have new axes. For example, in a dimension 3 array (e.g. a cube) you will have 3 axes (row, column, depth).

When you pass the axis in the `np.argmax` you are telling numpy along which axis you want the maximum argument. 3 will throw an error because your array only has 3 axes (0, 1, 2).

[Here](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-axes-explained/) is an article about numpy arrays axes.